# Open Framework: The EmptyExample app does not work in iOS8. "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386"

Tags: ios, openframeworks

I started to try to launch open Framework project in iOS. However, I got some errors during launch the example project.
I have no ideas how should I do. Any help will be appreciated.

What I did:

1 Download Open Framework for iOS

http://www.openframeworks.cc/versions/v0.8.4/of_v0.8.4_ios_release.zip

2 Change Deployment Target to 8.3. And then Launch Example project

/Users/Zono/Downloads/of_v0.8.4_ios_release/apps/myApps/emptyExample/emptyExample.xcodeproj

3 I got some errors below.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ../../../libs/FreeImage/lib/ios/freeimage.a, missing required architecture i386 in file ../../../libs/FreeImage/lib/ios/freeimage.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file ../../../libs/glu/lib/ios/glu-ios.a, missing required architecture i386 in file ../../../libs/glu/lib/ios/glu-ios.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_fwrite$UNIX2003", referenced from:
_WriteProc(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) in freeimage.a(FreeImageIO.o-i386)
LibRaw::dcraw_thumb_writer(char const*) in freeimage.a(libraw_cxx.o-i386)
opjimage_create in freeimage.a(image.o-i386)
pngdefault_write_data in freeimage.a(pngwio.o-i386)
LibRaw::ppm_thumb() in freeimage.a(dcraw_common.o-i386)
LibRaw::jpeg_thumb_writer(_sFILE*, char*, int) in freeimage.a(dcrawcommon.o-i386)
LibRaw::write_ppm_tiff() in freeimage.a(dcraw_common.o-i386)
...
"_mktime$UNIX2003", referenced from:
LibRaw::get_timestamp(int) in freeimage.a(dcraw_common.o-i386)
LibRaw::parse_rollei() in freeimage.a(dcraw_common.o-i386)
LibRaw::parse_riff() in freeimage.a(dcraw_common.o-i386)
"_strerror$UNIX2003", referenced from:
Iex::throwErrnoExc(std::string const&, int) in freeimage.a(IexThrowErrnoExc.o-i386)
"_strtod$UNIX2003", referenced from:
pnghandle_sCAL in freeimage.a(pngrutil.o-i386)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

freeimage.a and glu-ios.a are seems to be existed in the folder.

My Xcode is Version 6.3.1.

Comment: What device type are you building to run on?

Comment: @Phillip Mills Thanks for your comment. The problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

@jeonghopark told the answer to me in the openFrameworks's forum. It worked normally.

I put this code below @jeonghopark told me.

```
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofApp.h"

extern "C"{
    size_t fwrite$UNIX2003( const void *a, size_t b, size_t c, FILE *d )
    {
        return fwrite(a, b, c, d);
    }
    char* strerror$UNIX2003( int errnum )
    {
        return strerror(errnum);
    }
    time_t mktime$UNIX2003(struct tm * a)
    {
        return mktime(a);
    }
    double strtod$UNIX2003(const char * a, char ** b) {
        return strtod(a, b);
    }
}

int main(){

    ofSetupOpenGL(1024,768, OF_FULLSCREEN);         // <-------- setup the GL context

    ofRunApp(new ofApp);
}
```